# Firebase unauth - Throws an error: permission_denied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am using an AngularJS application with a mix of Firebase and AngularFire. When I click a button that calls a `Logout()` function, the `Logout()` calls `ref.unauth()` but it causes an error occasionally. The error comes from the Firebase library: 
"The Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data."

```
//1. Unauthorize
var ref = new Firebase($scope.firebaseurl+'/'+jsonArray.UserProfile.UID);
ref.off();
ref.unauth();
```

I tried creating a service in angular to persist the variables so I can destroy them when logging out, but it doesn't seem to have an affect.

Is there a way to suppress that error or unbind all links ?

Should I call `ref.unauth()` on all variations of firebaseurl + '/'.... ?

Please let me know if I should include more info.

Thanks for the help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up digging a bit more deep and the solution I found that works all the time is adding a scope.xyz.$destory(); to the $firebaseArrays/Objects.

    `$scope.$on( '$destroy', function() {
        $scope.array1.$destroy();
    });`

So basically when the view / scope gets destroyed which happens also on logout, the firebaseArrays/Objects are forcibly destroyed. Hope this helps anyone running into this problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Are you destroying all objects/arrays/etc. in every controller? That seems like a real pain if we have to do manual clean up everywhere....

It seems like somewhere in the firebase code it's trying to access the user AFTER it logged them out

Comment: I found the reference causing the issue for me. I found encapsulating all of the firebase refs into services makes it way easier.